# How can I check if my index is out of range of the array?

Tags: haskell

I am currently a newbie just starting out.

My code :

```
atIndex :: [a] -> Int -> a
atIndex [] _ = error "error"
atIndex (xs) n = head (drop n xs)
```

The first argument is my array and the second my index (ex: `atIndex [1,2,3] 1;` I will get 2).

I want to know how can I send an error or message if my index is out of range of the array ?

example: `atIndex [1,2,3] -1` or `atIndex [1,2,3] 3` and get `"error, your index is out of range"`.

Comment: Hint: use a `guard`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `[a]` is **not** an array type, it's a list. (And as such you should normally avoid indexing into it at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a *guard* so:

```
atIndex :: [a] -> Int -> a
atIndex [] _ = error "error"
atIndex (x:_) 0 = …
atIndex (_:xs) n
  | n < 0 = …
  | otherwise = atIndex … …
```

In Haskell, one howeve usually does *not* work with errors, but encodes it in the output, by using a `Maybe a` or `Either String a` type for example where `Nothing`/`Left "error message"` is used if the input is invalid, and `Just x`/`Right x` in case the input is valid with `x` the result wrapped in a `Just` or `Right`, so:

```
atIndex :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
atIndex [] _ = Nothing
atIndex (x:_) 0 = Just …
atIndex (_:xs) n
  | n < 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = atIndex … …
```

Answer (score 2):

For variety, this is what the code looks like when using `if` / `else` and `Either`.

Note 1. When using guards you don't have `=` in the declaration, whereas you do with `if` / `else`.

Note 2. As with `Maybe`, where the return type is `Just value` or `Nothing`, with `Either` the return type is `Left error` or `Right value`. Unlike `Maybe`, `Either` includes an error message.

```
atIndex :: [a] -> Int -> Either String a
atIndex [] _ = Left "Error"
atIndex xs n = 
    if n >=0 && n < length(xs) then
        Right $ head (drop n xs)
    else
        Left "Error"
```

Comment: This use of `length` is problematic. It unnecessarily traverses the whole list, which is inefficient and (more importantly) means that your function does not terminate on valid inputs (infinite lists, when `n >= 0`). You can also replace `head (drop n xs)` with `xs !! n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an `error` on invalid index, the built-in indexing function `(!!)` already does this. Its definition, found on page 118 of the [Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf), is as follows:

```
(!!)                :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs     !! n | n < 0 = error "Prelude.!!: negative index"
[]     !! _         = error "Prelude.!!: index too large"
(x:_)  !! 0         = x
(_:xs) !! n         = xs !! (n-1)
```

Other options are to use a `Maybe` or `Either` to represent the result. The implementation would be similar to the above, but returning `Nothing`/`Left` on errors and returning `Just`/`Right` otherwise.

Note that `head` is a partial function, and `listToMaybe` should be used instead when the list could be empty. Here are some implementations using `drop` like your function:

```
atIndexMaybe :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
atIndexMaybe xs n
    | n < 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = listToMaybe (drop n xs)

atIndexEither :: [a] -> Int -> Either String a
atIndexEither xs n
    | n < 0 = Left "Negative index"
    | otherwise = case drop n xs of
        [] -> Left "Index out of range"
        (x:_) -> Right x
```